# Element doesn't disappear for some browsers

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Put simply, loading animation (with white background) should appear as the homepage loads. It should then disappear following loading completion. Working fine for Chrome, but not IE and Firefox (animation works but does not disappear, which may be JS related).

***EDIT - I've temporarily removed the html as the website is active and needed by our customers.

Take a look here: www.championfreight.co.nz

HTML

```
<div id="backgroundcolor" style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; left:0%; top:0%; z-index:1997">
<div id="followingBallsG" style="left:50%; margin-left:-50px; top:50%; z-index:1998">
<div id="followingBallsG_1" class="followingBallsG">
</div>
<div id="followingBallsG_2" class="followingBallsG">
</div>
<div id="followingBallsG_3" class="followingBallsG">
</div>
<div id="followingBallsG_4" class="followingBallsG">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function()
{ 
document.getElementById("followingBallsG").style.visibility = "hidden" 
document.getElementById("backgroundcolor").style.visibility = "hidden" 
}
```

CSS

```
#backgroundcolor{
background-color:white
}

#followingBallsG{
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:8px;
}

.followingBallsG{
background-color:#000000;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:8px;
height:8px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-moz-animation-name:bounce_followingBallsG;
-moz-animation-duration:1.4s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-direction:linear;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-animation-name:bounce_followingBallsG;
-webkit-animation-duration:1.4s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction:linear;
-ms-border-radius:4px;
-ms-animation-name:bounce_followingBallsG;
-ms-animation-duration:1.4s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-ms-animation-direction:linear;
-o-border-radius:4px;
-o-animation-name:bounce_followingBallsG;
-o-animation-duration:1.4s;
-o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-o-animation-direction:linear;
border-radius:4px;
animation-name:bounce_followingBallsG;
animation-duration:1.4s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-direction:linear;
}

#followingBallsG_1{
-moz-animation-delay:0s;
}

#followingBallsG_1{
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
}

#followingBallsG_1{
-ms-animation-delay:0s;
}

#followingBallsG_1{
-o-animation-delay:0s;
}

#followingBallsG_1{
animation-delay:0s;
}

#followingBallsG_2{
-moz-animation-delay:0.14s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.14s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.14s;
-o-animation-delay:0.14s;
animation-delay:0.14s;
}

#followingBallsG_3{
-moz-animation-delay:0.28s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.28s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.28s;
-o-animation-delay:0.28s;
animation-delay:0.28s;
}

#followingBallsG_4{
-moz-animation-delay:0.42s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.42s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.42s;
-o-animation-delay:0.42s;
animation-delay:0.42s;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_followingBallsG{
0%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

50%{
left:93px;
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_followingBallsG{
0%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

50%{
left:93px;
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_followingBallsG{
0%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

50%{
left:93px;
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

}

@-o-keyframes bounce_followingBallsG{
0%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

50%{
left:93px;
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

}

@keyframes bounce_followingBallsG{
0%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

50%{
left:93px;
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
}

}
```

Comment: You may want to put `;` at the end of the JavaScript lines. it's generally good practice. Maybe it's only here where it's missing. Still. Also, the white background for the body, another missing `;`. It may help because various browsers accept such missing end of line in different ways...

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've made the changes and still no luck. Still tinkering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I get it. But that is likely to not work in Firefox because they turn off animations while "loading another page". The only way to have an animation working is to use AJAX to do the loading. That's a bit of work and you may have a problem with search engines if you do that because AJAX won't be run by search engines and you will not get any clicks from search engines, so bad idea...

Comment: The animation works fine, but I think this entire issue centers on the JS. It's just not removing the animation and white background when the page loads. I'm wondering if other JS resourced by the page is causing problems. Exploring.

Comment: Tried this - animation now doesn't appear at all..

`$(document).ready(function()
{ 
document.getElementById("followingBallsG").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
document.getElementById("backgroundcolor").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
});`

Comment: Tried this - animation isn't working...

`$(document).ready(function()
{ 
$('#followingBallsG').hide(); 
$('#backgroundcolor').hide(); 
});`

Comment: I think I've fixed it...

    `$(window).load(function()
    { 
    $('#followingBallsG').hide(); 
    $('#backgroundcolor').hide(); 
    });`

Open to any feedback if you think otherwise. 

Special thank you to those that assisted.

Comment: Ah... you did not mention the fact that you could use jQuery. Note that the hide() uses the `display: none` CSS and not the `visibility: hidden`.